# Publish of application fails to find file that exists

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've run into this issue when trying to publish my application today that I have published many times before.  I'm trying to publish to a directory.

The issue I have is, if I go to my app directory `C:\www\clients\clientsite\app\clientproject\Properties\PublishProfiles` where the error below says it can't find the file I can clearly see the `git.pubxml` file.

`Copying file Properties\PublishProfiles\git.pubxml to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Properties\PublishProfiles\git.pubxml failed. Could not find file 'Properties\PublishProfiles\git.pubxml'.`

I've checked directory security settings and those are proper. I tried deleting my `bin` and `obj` but nothing is making a difference.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS was saying it couldn't find that file because the `git.pubxml`  file in that directory was of type `USER File` and it needed to be `PUBXML`. When I added the correct file type from another version of that same project, I was able to publish the project again. I believe the `PUBXML` file was removed by mistake in source control.

Answer (score 10):

Often times the solution here is to edit the project file itself in notepad.

The trick to finding the afflicted path is to inspect the OUTPUT window, not the ERROR LIST window.

Once you find the afflicted file path, search for it in the project file and remove the reference.

In most cases the troublesome lines in the project file look like :

```
<Content include="{your path}" />
```

Continue to remove the includes until publishing works.

**IMPORTANT:** if you keep Visual Studio open while you're doing this, you must accept the "reload all" prompt.

Comment: For me this helped, as there were lines that were connected to old publishing profiles. Removed them and my problem was solved.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Searched the .csproj file for the .pubxml file and found some old profiles listed. Removed those and published again. Worked that time.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this after removing all unversioned files from my filesystem (which caused some `.pubxml.user` files to be lost.

If you right click the project node and click "publish", then select the publish profile that is causing problems, then simply close the publish dialog, Visual Studio will ask if you want to save changes... when you click yes, it regenerate the `.pubxml.user` file and everything works again.

Comment: Thank you!  This was the fix for me.

Answer (score 6):

Have you ensured that the file actually exists **in the project?** I have had problems working in a team where some file I wrote ended up not appearing in VS as a project file, so when we published, it didn't exist in the publish. If you can't find it inside VS, ensure that you are not debugging, and drop the file into the project file structure, then publish as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. While your answer didn't exactly solve my issue it lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It usually happens to binary files after updating it. Some packages remove it's own .xml and .pubxml files, while visual studio still believes that it is a part of the project.

What you need to do it to check for a **Yellow Triangle** besides the file name in the project directory tree, and remove that files, they're useless since your project compiles without errors.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the publishing settings. if you check "Precompile during publishing" this will recreate your .pubxml.user file

Answer (score 0):

I looked in Solution Explorer under the PublishProfiles section and found that the file was excluded and had a "!" by it showing a warning that the file wasn't found. I deleted it, then went into my Publish settings to edit a profile. I changed something (for me to compile files during publish.) Then I tried republishing the solution, and it worked!